# Debugging shader script in GLSL ES - Game Maker 2 (CompileError)

Tags: shaders, glsl, game-maker, fragment-shader, game-maker-studio-2

I am trying to use [this shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wsS3RD) in the game I am making with Game Maker Studio 2.

I tried to convert it for GM2 and here is my result:

Shader type I used on GM2 is `GLSL ES`

**myshader.vsh**

```
attribute vec3 in_Position;                  // (x,y,z)
//attribute vec3 in_Normal;                  // (x,y,z)     unused in this shader.
attribute vec4 in_Colour;                    // (r,g,b,a)
attribute vec2 in_TextureCoord;              // (u,v)

varying vec2 v_vTexcoord;
varying vec4 v_vColour;

void main()
{
    vec4 object_space_pos = vec4( in_Position.x, in_Position.y, in_Position.z, 1.0);
    gl_Position = gm_Matrices[MATRIX_WORLD_VIEW_PROJECTION] * object_space_pos;
    
    v_vColour = in_Colour;
    v_vTexcoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

**myshader.fsh**

```
varying vec2 v_vTexcoord;
varying vec4 v_vColour;

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float pixelSize;
uniform float gamma;

void main(){
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy; 
    float alpha = 1.0;
    vec4 color = v_vColour * texture2D( gm_BaseTexture, v_vTexcoord );
    gl_FragColor = color;
  
    float pixelSize = 3.0;
    float gamma = 3.0;
  
    vec2 pseudoResolution = floor(resolution.xy / pixelSize);
    vec2 pseudoPixel = floor(gl_FragCoord.xy / float(pixelSize));
    vec2 pseudoUv = pseudoPixel / pseudoResolution;
  
    vec3 tex = texture2D(gm_BaseTexture, pseudoUv).rgb;
    float bw = (tex.r + tex.g + tex.b) / gamma;
    float col = 0.0;
    
    if(bw > 0.8) {
        col = 1.0;} 
    else if (bw > 0.6) {
        col = float(!(int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 == 0 && int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2 != 0));} 
        else if (bw > 0.4) {
        col = float((int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 + int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2) % 2 == 0);} 
        else if(bw > 0.2) {
        col = float(int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 == 0 && int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2 == 0);}
    gl_FragColor = color * vec4(col, col, col, alpha);}
```

But this is just throwing this compile error:

`Fragment Shader: shd_1BitDithering at line 30 : ''`

Line 30 is:

```
25    if(bw > 0.8) {
26      col = 1.0;} 
27  else if (bw > 0.6) {
28      col = float(!(int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 == 0 && int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2 != 0));}
29      else if (bw > 0.4) {
-> 30   col = float((int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 + int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2) % 2 == 0);} 
31      else if(bw > 0.2) {
32      col = float(int(pseudoPixel.x) % 2 == 0 && int(pseudoPixel.y) % 2 == 0);}
33  gl_FragColor = color * vec4(col, col, col, alpha);}
```

Coming from a Python background, I really have no idea how to debug that message.

Any clue on how could I make this shader work, or how could I understand what the problem is?

Comment: The code in the whole shader and the code you have pasted in to highlight the erroring line seem to differ as the latter one is using the word `mod`, what's going on there? Also my initial guess would be that the GLSL version does not support the modulo operator, does the error disappear if you replace `x % a` with `mod(x, a)`?

Comment: That was the problem, % is not supported. I used mod(x,a) and everything went fine

Comment: If that solved your problem, want to post the solution as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to get it working.

My code had many problems, first of all the modulus operand `%` which is not supported by GLSL ES.

I had to use the `mod` function and, as I found [on the official docs](http://docs.gl/el3/mod), the function needs to be called with the two operands as parameters. As I can understand from the docs, I also had to give the value to divide for as a float.

Applied this, the code gets more and more confusing because of the many parentheses: on line 30 the original script is making a modulus of a modulus, which has been a bit confusing to convert with the mod function syntax.

Fixed this, it was giving out an error on the "==" operand, so I made any number involved in a comparison a float, this fixed it.

The updated code (only the if cycle) is here:

```
if (bw > 0.8) 
{
    col = 1.0;
}
else if (bw > 0.6)
{
    col = float(!(mod(pseudoPixel.x, 2.0) == 0.0) && (mod(pseudoPixel.y, 2.0) != 0.0));
}
else if (bw > 0.4)
{
    col = float(mod((mod(pseudoPixel.x, 2.0) + mod(pseudoPixel.y, 2.0)), 2.0) == 0.0);
} 
else if (bw > 0.2) 
{
    col = float((mod(pseudoPixel.x, 2.0) == 0.0) && (mod(pseudoPixel.y, 2.0) == 0.0));
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your nested moduli if you want. odd + odd = even, odd + even = odd, even + even = even. So mod(x + y, 2.0) will give you the same result as mod(mod(x, 2) + mod(y, 2), 2)